# TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desending'

Tags: python, sorting

***Code->***

```
sort_df=df.sort_values('Total(course content accseeed)',desending='True')
sort_df
```

### ***Error->***

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
             <ipython-input-42-0767ca457704> in <module>()
              ----> 1 sort_df=df.sort_values('Total(course content accseeed)',desending='True')
                    2 sort_df

             TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desending'
```

Comment: FYI: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Please don't replace your original question with the fully new text. I rolled it back, because people answered your original question. Keep your original text and after it write **“Append:”** or **“Edit:”** with a consequent text.

Answer (score 1):

using `ascending=False` will sort your values in descending order + `desending` is not an attribute for the `sort_values` method.

```
df.sort_values('Total(course content accseeed)', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct argument is to set `ascending` to `False`:

```
df.sort_values('Total(course content accseeed)',ascending=False)
```

Comment: False isn't a string, remove ' ' from Fase.

Comment: Correct objection. Corrected